# How to delete a pdf if download was incomplete in android?

Tags: java, android, pdf, download

I am downloading a pdf file from my server.Recently I encountered that
when my internet was disconnected while the download was in progress I
couldn't open the pdf file because it was incomplete.How can I delete
a file programmatically if the download was incomplete and a file with
that extension was saved in the process? This is the code I am
currently using to download the pdf from a server.

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    final int notify_id = 1;
    final NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    private String resp;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        int count;
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Download Status...");
        builder.setContentText("Download in Progress...");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "LENGTH OF FILE : " + lengthOfFile);

            String fileName = params[0].substring(params[0].lastIndexOf('/') + 1, params[0].length());
            Log.d("FILENAME", fileName);
            resp = fileName;

            if (isSDPresent) {

                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("sdcard/shatayushi/" + fileName);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir() + "/shatayushi/" + fileName);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return params[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String filename) {
        Log.d("PARAM", filename);

        String fname = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1, filename.length());

        int position = Arrays.asList(pdf_url).indexOf(filename);
        Log.d("Position",String.valueOf(position));
        String magazine_id = magazine_names[position];

        if (isSDPresent) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
            builder.setContentText("Download Complete...");
            NM.notify(notify_id, builder.build());

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String device_imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            update_info(device_imei,magazine_id);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/shatayushi/" + fname);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MuPDFActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setData(uri);

            startActivity(intent);

        } else {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
            builder.setContentText("Download Complete...");
            NM.notify(notify_id, builder.build());

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(getFilesDir() + "/shatayushi/" + fname);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MuPDFActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setData(uri);

            startActivity(intent);

        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", values[0]);
        progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        builder.setProgress(100, Integer.parseInt(values[0]), false);
        NM.notify(notify_id, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @PaoloForgia for the edit can you help with a solution?

Comment: what about `file.delete()`?

Comment: Is there a way to find out if the download was incomplete or a incomplete file got saved in java.So based on that condition I can delete the file.

Comment: Compare the file length of the downloaded file with the expected length. or delete the file in case the dowload doesn't complete (progressbar not reaching 100%)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#length()

Answer (score 1):

You can just get a pointer to the file and use "delete()" method

```
String fileName = "my_file"; //your file name
File parentFile; //get your parent file 
File myFile = new File(parentFile, fileName);
myFile.delete();
```

Comment: Thank you.Is there a way to find out if the download was incomplete or a incomplete file got saved in java.So based on that condition I can delete the file in my existing code.

Comment: Instead of doing :
return params[0];
just set a variable StringToReturnToPostExecute to null until the end of the download where you will set it to params[0] if the download is successful.

Then in your onPostExecute method, if the received parameter is null, you ll know something went wrong and from there you ll just delete the file

Comment: interesting question, the problem with your code is that a lot can go wrong I never thought of how to handle big file downloading tasks but think  of the following situations - wifi/3g is off, no reception, server is down etc..). now you need to think what the outcome will be in each of this cases so to simplify things i would suggest to check the file size in the beginning of the download and the file size in the end of the download (when onPostExcute is called).

Comment: you can use - **int length = inputStream.available();** to check the input stream size in bytes and the compare it to **myFile.length()** , pay attention that input stream avaibevle function returns int and file length function returns long

Comment: Last suggestion i can give you, after you make it work and you understand how to handle files and streams delete your code and write it again using REST api (i.e - retrofit, okhttpclient, Android Asynchronous Http Client, etc..). for images use glide, or picasso.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can handle the network I/O exceptions first instead of catching "Exception".

   // Exception thrown when network timeout occurs

   catch (InterruptedIOException iioe)
   {
      System.err.println ("Remote host timed out during read operation");
   }

   // Exception thrown when general network I/O error occurs

   catch (IOException ioe)
   {
      System.err.println ("Network I/O exception- " + ioe);
   }
   then

   catch(Exception e) {System.err.println ("Exception - " + ioe);
   }
2. When you get the network type of error, you can then check that whether the file has been created/exists and then you can delete it using the following code,

   File fdelete = new File(uri.getPath());
       if (fdelete.exists()) {
           if (fdelete.delete()) {
               System.out.println("file Deleted :" + uri.getPath());
           } else {
               System.out.println("file not Deleted :" + uri.getPath());
           }
       }

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Roee answer that I completed a bit up, here should be a working example :

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    final int notify_id = 1;
    final NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    private String resp;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        int count;

        String stringToReturnToPostExecute = null;

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Download Status...");
        builder.setContentText("Download in Progress...");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "LENGTH OF FILE : " + lengthOfFile);

            String fileName = params[0].substring(params[0].lastIndexOf('/') + 1, params[0].length());
            Log.d("FILENAME", fileName);
            resp = fileName;

            if (isSDPresent) {

                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("sdcard/shatayushi/" + fileName);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir() + "/shatayushi/" + fileName);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
                stringToReturnToPostExecute = params[0];
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringToReturnToPostExecute ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String filename) {
        Log.d("PARAM", filename);

        if(filename == null) {
           //TODO delete your file here and dismissthe Dialog as well
        }
        String fname = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1, filename.length());

        int position = Arrays.asList(pdf_url).indexOf(filename);
        Log.d("Position",String.valueOf(position));
        String magazine_id = magazine_names[position];

        if (isSDPresent) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
            builder.setContentText("Download Complete...");
            NM.notify(notify_id, builder.build());

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String device_imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            update_info(device_imei,magazine_id);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/shatayushi/" + fname);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MuPDFActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setData(uri);

            startActivity(intent);

        } else {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
            builder.setContentText("Download Complete...");
            NM.notify(notify_id, builder.build());

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(getFilesDir() + "/shatayushi/" + fname);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MuPDFActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setData(uri);

            startActivity(intent);

        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", values[0]);
        progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        builder.setProgress(100, Integer.parseInt(values[0]), false);
        NM.notify(notify_id, builder.build());
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    final int notify_id = 1;
    final NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    private String resp;
    int lengthOfFile;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        int count;
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Download Status...");
        builder.setContentText("Download in Progress...");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "LENGTH OF FILE : " + lengthOfFile);

            String fileName = params[0].substring(params[0].lastIndexOf('/') + 1, params[0].length());
            Log.d("FILENAME", fileName);
            resp = fileName;

            if (isSDPresent) {

                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("sdcard/shatayushi/" + fileName);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir() + "/shatayushi/" + fileName);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return params[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String filename) {
        Log.d("PARAM", filename);

        String fname = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1, filename.length());

        Log.d("LENGTH OF FILE : ",String.valueOf(lengthOfFile));

        int position = Arrays.asList(pdf_url).indexOf(filename);
        Log.d("Position",String.valueOf(position));
        String magazine_id = magazine_names[position];

        if (isSDPresent) {

            File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/shatayushi/" +fname);
            if (f.length()<lengthOfFile)
            {
                if (f.delete())
                {
                    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                    dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
                    builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                    builder.setContentText("Download was interrupted please try again!");
                    NM.notify(notify_id, builder.build());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download was interrupted please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("Del","File deleted");
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File not deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("NOTDel","File not deleted");
                }
            }else {
                progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
                builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                builder.setContentText("Download Complete...");
                NM.notify(notify_id, builder.build());

                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                String device_imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
                // update_info(device_imei,magazine_id);

                dbHandler.updateDownloadStatus(magazine_id, "YES");
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/shatayushi/" + fname);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MuPDFActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                intent.setData(uri);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

        } else {

            File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/shatayushi/" +fname);
            if (f.length()<lengthOfFile)
            {
                if (f.delete())
                {
                    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                    dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
                    builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                    builder.setContentText("Download was interrupted please try again!");
                    NM.notify(notify_id, builder.build());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download was interrupted please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("Del","File deleted");
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File not deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("NOTDel","File not deleted");
                }
            }else
            {
                dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
                builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                builder.setContentText("Download Complete...");
                NM.notify(notify_id, builder.build());

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(getFilesDir() + "/shatayushi/" + fname);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MuPDFActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                intent.setData(uri);

                startActivity(intent);
            }


        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", values[0]);
        progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        builder.setProgress(100, Integer.parseInt(values[0]), false);
        NM.notify(notify_id, builder.build());
    }
}
```

I finally figured it out Sorry @Rotwang and thank you @user3793589.